# how to get click event of row element of jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Can you please tell me how how to get click event of row element of jstree ? 
I make a demo of jstree in my fiddle .it is made in panel .you have to  press "open panel " button to check panel

I want to click event of jstree element to get it id on click ?
For preparation of tree I have to press "add test case button" many times and then press "open panel" button.

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZLe2R/6/

```
function addMenuItemsOfTestSuit(id){

 var menuid = "menu_" + id;
       var ref = $('#tree').jstree(true);
        alert('thank')
    ref.create_node("#", {"id" : menuid, "text" : id});

        ref.deselect_all();

}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use this event listener:

```
$('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert("node_id: " + data.node.id); });
```

Look [jsTree API events](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event) for a list of events.

EDIT: created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7ar9/4/

Comment: can you please use fiddle ?

Comment: can we expand submenu option after click of "text" like "tc_1" and "tc_2"

Comment: if you mean how to get the text of the node just use `data.node.text`, instead of `data.node.id`. Look at the fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/y7ar9/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GS4u3/8/ please check fiddle .I just want same as it is in this fiddle

Comment: Press "add" button two or three time .then select any item it gives id.if you select item and press add it add submenu .till now it is fine

Comment: in obove fiddle you see if you click any text like "1" and "2" it will expand if element have child .I need that functionality

Comment: if you want how you addsubmenu in you answer fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y7ar9/4/ .please click "add testcase" two or three times.and click any row .then again click "add test case" .it generate submenu

Comment: This event is fired only when select the node. In deselect node isn't fired!

Comment: Personally I like event 'activate_node' instead. if you are doing a postback on node change and the page is reloaded and the node is still selected it will not cause another event to fire causing an endless postback loop.  $('#jstree').on('activate_node.jstree', function (e, data)

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
$(document).on('click', '.jstree-anchor', function(e) {...});
```

You may want to move your click handler to its own function and get the `id` from the anchor's parent:

```
$(document).on('click', '.jstree-anchor', function(e) {
    var anchorId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var clickId = anchorId.substring(anchorId.indexOf('_') + 1, anchorId.length);
    onMenuItemClick(clickId, e);
});
$(document).on('click', '.clickTestCaseRow', function (e) {
    onMenuItemClick(this.id, e);
});
function onMenuItemClick(clickId, e) {
    hideDisplayView();
    displayNewView(clickId);
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

**[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/ZLe2R/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like event 'activate_node' instead. if you do a postback on node selection change and the page is reloaded and the node is still selected it will not cause another event to fire causing an endless postback loop.

```
$('#jstree').on('activate_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
     if (data == undefined || data.node == undefined || data.node.id == undefined)
                return;
    alert('clicked node: ' + data.node.id);
});
```